# Want to Select each field based on another field and create new columns for each

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Hopefully I am explaining this well. I have a stored procedure that we use to populate a report in crystal. I need to change some of the fields but I need to pull two fields from a single column that is designated by two different keys.

Both fields have the same Job number which is the searchable field used to select records. I am trying to fill one field in based on spare5 = a and the other on spare5 = b. I would also like to create new columns that would hold each item number (item_numb_sparea, item_numb_spareb). Is this possible? I am very new to sql and I think this could be simple it's just something I haven't encountered yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make two formulas in Crystal reports that pulls the data out like you want.

It depends on if you need this stored procedure for other things that do not require this or this change would cause problems elsewhere. If you are unsure i would create the formulas.

[HERE](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/index?rid=/library/uuid/b06678d0-a751-2e10-cd87-aa3682a03ee5&overridelayout=true) is some info on creating conditional formulas in Crystal Reports.

If you choose to change the stored procedure it should also be simple, the core of the procedure is likely a select statement.

[HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345356.aspx) is some info on modifying a stored procedure.